# issue installing h2o on r

Tags: r, installation, h2o

I used install package to install h2o. While I could do h2o.init(), the h2o.autoML function isn't found:

```
could not find function "h2o.automl"
```

After some searching I installed the 'nightly bleeding edge' [version](https://www.h2o.ai/download/) in tar.gz. but after install that even h2o.init() no longer works and shows this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘h2o’ in get(method, envir = home):
 lazy-load database '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/h2o/R/h2o.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In .registerS3method(fin[i, 1], fin[i, 2], fin[i, 3], fin[i, 4],  :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In get(method, envir = home) :
restarting interrupted promise evaluation
3: In get(method, envir = home) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
```

Comment: Does this one solve your problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/CQ96Lwlv4PY

Comment: this is the one I tried which even stopped h2o.init() from working..thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to install h2o to a work computer? Your company's firewall may be blocking access to the package if a call is being made to an S3 bucket in AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h2o.automl()` function has been included in the nightly releases for the past 2 months, so it should be in there if you have correctly installed the package.  I recommend the nightly release over the 3.12 "preview release" because 3.12 has some bugs in it with AutoML.

The nightly release (from last night) can be installed here:

```
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3978/R")
```

Those reading this later, should visit [this page](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html) to get the link to the most recent version.

After installation in R, start up the H2O cluster and verify the version.  It should be the same as below:

```
> h2o.init()
Reading in config file: ./../../.h2oconfig

H2O is not running yet, starting it now...

Note:  In case of errors look at the following log files:
    /var/folders/2j/jg4sl53d5q53tc2_nzm9fz5h0000gn/T//RtmpV47QKn/h2o_me_started_from_r.out
    /var/folders/2j/jg4sl53d5q53tc2_nzm9fz5h0000gn/T//RtmpV47QKn/h2o_me_started_from_r.err

java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Starting H2O JVM and connecting: .. Connection successful!

R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
    H2O cluster uptime:         1 seconds 983 milliseconds 
    H2O cluster version:        3.13.0.3978 
    H2O cluster version age:    10 hours and 6 minutes  
    H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_me_flj500 
    H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
    H2O cluster total memory:   3.56 GB 
    H2O cluster total cores:    8 
    H2O cluster allowed cores:  8 
    H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
    H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
    H2O Connection port:        54321 
    H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
    H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
    H2O API Extensions:         XGBoost, Algos, AutoML, Core V3, Core V4 
    R Version:                  R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
```

AutoML will be included in the next stable release of H2O, 3.14.0.1, to be released in the next week or two.