# installing H2O.ai Python driver matching server's version?

Tags: python, h2o

I'm trying to install `3.14.0.1` to match the server's version.

PyPi has a limited set listed at:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/h2o

The documentation only offers a (current?) install command using a wheel

http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/1/index.html

`pip install http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-wolpert/1/Python/h2o-3.18.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`

but there doesn't seem to be a list of previous versions ...

For reference, I found Anaconda  packages listed at (but doesn't have version I was looking for):

https://anaconda.org/h2oai/h2o/files

and Github project doesn't publish wheels directly:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/releases

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? I just did a google search of "h2o 3.14.0.1". http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/1/index.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511789/304690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to find the download artifacts for a specific H2O version x.y.z.w is to just do a google search of "h2o x.y.z.w".

Another trick is, if you have that version already running, you can go to the H2O Flow Web UI and find the documentation button.  Clicking that will take you to the online docs for that specific release.  You can tweak that URL so that it matches the form below:

- http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-BRANCH_NAME/BUILD_NUM/index.html

Comment: While searching didn't work for me, I also arrived to a similar solution. I found the build page at https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/releases/tag/jenkins-3.14.0.1 and based on that formulated the download URL as http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-weierstrass/1/h2o-3.14.0.1.zip
 (which zip happens to contain a ```python``` subdirectory with a pip installable ```whl``` inside)

Answer (score 0):

You can also install the wheel from it's location on your machine using the terminal:

> ( pip install h2o-3.14.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl)

The file can be located in your H2O installation folder at this path:

> h2o-3.14.0.1/python/h2o-3.14.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl